Why optical astronomical Interferometry is so much more difficult than combined radio telescopes aperture synthesis?
If they plan to achieve the resolution required to be able to see the black hole in the center of our galaxy by combining the radio telescopes a thousand kilometers apart, why they cannot do the same in the infrared/optical wavelengths?

Duplicate of https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29082/is-optical-vlbi-theoretically-feasible-if-not-why-not

This is better asked on astronomy stack exchange.

@EugeneStyer - Thanks. It was very informative. But I still don't understand why you have to see the same photon in telescopes a thousand miles apart? Why cannot you accumulate digital signatures from photons in different telescopes over a period of time and then combine them in a denser image (with higher resolution)?

Look at the frequency of visible light, then look at the frequency/clock speed of computers that you expect to be able to process them into digital signatures.

@fyrepenguin - I guess it is a question for physics stack exchange. If Hubble can take exposure over weeks, what does it have to do with frequency/clock speed?

@TheMatrixEquation-balance The way I understand it, if you want to do interferometry on digital signal data, you need your signal to be sampled many times faster than the signal frequency in order to get a datastream that's useable. Visible light is in the hundreds-of-terahertz range, so need a sampling system that's running in the petahertz at a minimum, and then you have to take your two (or more) data streams and get them aligned down to the femtosecond (millionth of a nanosecond) before your processing will work, and that's ... impractical.

There are visible interferometers, like COAST, but they use physical interference by having an underground tube between the two telescopes and using mirrors and lenses adjusted along a track to get the signals synchronized just right. Tom Scott did a video last year about the interferometry system at the Extremely Large Telescope in Chile and it's impressively difficult!

@DarthPseudonym interestingly enough, for large terrestrial radio telescope arrays like ALMA and the SKA (but not the EHT) signals from each of the elements are converted to light signals before being collected for interferometry. Of course they're down-converted and digitized signals at that point. For very large optical interferometric arrays they'd be down-converted (GHz to THz) and digitized as well.

@DarthPseudonym https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43623/7982 so Scott is oversimplifying when suggesting we can easily tape-record radio but never light. Both would use down conversion via heterodyning, and ALMA already DOES observe at (nearly) THz frequencies

@TheMatrixEquation-balance have a look at What is stopping Event Horizon Telescope the size of the Earth’s orbit? in Astronomy SE. It's not the same question but it may shed some light on the issues.

@uhoh - I am still shaky regarding the basic physics of that. How do you get more pixels (of the object) from multiple telescopes with the same lens diameter (vs one bigger lens)?

@TheMatrixEquation-balance if you can accept that because of the diffraction limi the larger an aperture is, the higher resolution (more useful pixels) the image will have, then think of an array spread out over 1 km or 1000 km as a single HUGE aperture with a correspondingly higher resolution. That's it in a nutshell, if you need more then ask "But how, actually, can a dozen small radio telescopes spread out over Earth really get the same kind of resolution as a single Earth-sized telescope?" in Astronomy SE.

@uhoh - Thanks. If you told me that a photon is a wave, and a small telescope would miss most of the waves (creating just a few pixels from a galaxy). But the larger mirror will catch more photon-waves and produce more pixels from the galaxy. On the other hand, trying to record (digitally) a photon-wave and then combine it with photon-waves from other telescopes - technically very difficult. Then it would give me some clues :)

@uhoh Yeah I wouldn't use Tom as a good source for scientific details, but the views of the alignment machinery were really impressive to me.
